# How to Add XML Element Types using Python Suds Client

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, suds, workday-api

I have been having trouble figuring out how to add element types using a Suds factory. My code is below:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
from suds.sax.text import Raw
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

username = 'username@tenant'
password = 'password'

url = 'https://wd2-impl- 
services1.workday.com/ccx/service/[tenant]/Revenue_Management/v31.1?wsdl'

client = Client(url, username = username, password = password, faults = False)

CustomerObjectType = client.factory.create('ns0:CustomerObjectType')

CustomerObjectType.ID = 'CUS3466'

FinancialsBusinessProcess = client.factory.create('ns0:Financials_Business_Process_ParametersType')

FinancialsBusinessProcess.Auto_Complete = 'true'

CustomerData = client.factory.create('ns0:Customer_WWS_DataType')

CustomerData.Customer_Name = 'Test'
CustomerData.Worktag_Only = 'false'
CustomerData.Submit = 'true'

CustomerData.Payment_Terms_Reference.ID = ['NET30', 'Customer_ID']

CustomerData.Default_Payment_Type_Reference.ID = ['PTY_CHECK', 'Payment_Terms_ID']

CustomerData.Included_Children_Reference = ['CUS3029', 'Customer_ID']

CustomerData.Business_Entity_Data.Business_Entity_Name = 'Test'

security = Security()

token = UsernameToken(username, password)

security.tokens.append(token)

client.set_options(wsse=security)

client.service.Submit_Customer('true', CustomerObjectType, FinancialsBusinessProcess, CustomerData)
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
ERROR:suds.client:<suds.sax.document.Document instance at 0x10eb0e488>
```

With the output:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': '""', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
DEBUG:suds.client:HTTP failed - 500 - Internal Server Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.validationError</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Validation error occurred. Element 'ID' is missing attribute 'type'</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <wd:Validation_Fault>
      <wd:Validation_Error>
        <wd:Message>Element 'ID' is missing attribute 'type'</wd:Message>
        <wd:Detail_Message>Element 'ID' is missing attribute 'type'</wd:Detail_Message>
        <wd:Xpath>/ns0:Submit_Customer_Request[1]/ns0:Customer_Data[1]/ns0:Payment_Terms_Reference[1]/ns0:ID[2]</wd:Xpath>
      </wd:Validation_Error>
    </wd:Validation_Fault>
  </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

The formatting given back by the suds factory for the "Payment_Terms_Reference" element is as follows:

```
   Payment_Terms_Reference = 
  (Payment_TermsObjectType){
     ID[] = 
        "NET30",
        "Customer_ID",
     _Descriptor = ""
  }
```

Where I am confused is that it looks like it is using the index

```
Payment_Terms_Reference[1]/ns0:ID[2]
```

to find the element type, but when I add more data to the list in the complex object type it doesn't solve the problem.

The current XML code that spits out for Payment_Terms_Reference when I run this code comes out as:

```
<ns0:Payment_Terms_Reference>
   <ns0:ID>PTY_CHECK</ns0:ID>
   <ns0:ID>Payment_Terms_ID</ns0:ID>
</ns0:Payment_Terms_Reference>
```

But I think I need it to format like:

```
<ns0:Payment_Terms_Reference>
    <ns0:ID ns0:type="Payment_Terms_ID">ID</ns0:ID>
</ns0:Payment_Terms_Reference>
```

If anyone knows what might help me solve this problem, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a factory for the Payment_TermsObjectType

```
paymenttype = client.factory.create('ns0:Payment_TermsObjectIDType')
paymenttype._type = "PTY_CHECK"
paymenttype.value = "Payment_Type_ID"

CustomerData.Payment_Terms_Reference.ID = paymenttype
```